# How to post a string to a rest service using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, ajax, rest

Have been using `$resource.save(object)`; to post my objects to the rest service but this time I don't want the object to be marshalled. I need it to be posted as `text/plain`.
Is there an easy way of doing this using **angularJS**?

Comment: uses $http to send text/plain

Comment: tried using this method but it is still sending it as json, is there some way I cant explicitly say I want it sent as a String / as it is

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem.

Used the config parameters in the `.save` or `.post` functions to set the header content-types.

`var config = {
     headers : {
         'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
     }
 };
 $http.post(theURL, theBody, config)`

Comment: It's an important question. You can sign your own answer as correct.